# Event listeners in Codedui like Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, coded-ui-tests

I am trying to write the low level logging (my own html file) like clicking and entering text into the elements.

Is there any possible way to get those details after/before clicking the element like what we have in Selenium Event Listeners.

Comment: What do you get from Selenium that you would like from CodedUI?  Can you post an example of what you can do in Selenium?

Comment: @MPavlak I am generating my own log using selenium event listeners after every click or entering text. I want to do the same using CodedUI.

Comment: I'm not aware of anything like that.  However, you can write an abstraction over your code where you can inject logging. http://michaelpavlakcoding.blogspot.com/2016/06/decomposing-page-objects.html  This approach would require inline logging, though.

Comment: @VaraPrasad Do you mean that you need a log file with screenshots for every step being performed?

Comment: @RajeshS Not exactly. I just need the log of every step performed on the elements like clicking and entering data.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways that i would suggest.
(I) **CodedUI Provides you QT.Agent32 to produce logs of your execution. To use it, follow the below steps.**

1) Open the QTAgent32_40.exe.config file. *By default, this file is located in :\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE.*

2) Modify the value for EqtTraceLevel to the log level you want.(from level 1 to 4)
3) Save the file.
4) Open AppConfig File in codedUI Project, and paste this code under the config node.

```
<system.diagnostics>
<switches>
<add name="EqtTraceLevel" value="4"/>
</switches>
</system.diagnostics>
```

5) And in TestMethod enable this method like below,

```
LoggerOverrideState = HtmlLoggerState.AllActionSnapshot;
```

**(II) Create Customized using File IO**
1) Write a method to write the input in the newly created File (.txt or .excel or whatever). Say the method is Runlog(string input){} in a class called Report.cs
2) Let the input be whatever you intend to give. Example : clicked Submit button, Entered username.
3) Call this method with relevant input passing in it representing what action it has performed. Example: Report.Runlog("Clicked Submit Button");
4) Call this after every action. i know its a bit boring to call this after each action. but it's useful when you use a keyword driven framework.
Hope it gives you an idea. Good luck!!